# Ruby ERB Page: Render two partials side by side in a for loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I'm new to Ruby ERB pages and am trying to use one to render my blog. Currently I have this for loop which renders one post per row on the blog page

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <%= render :partial => 'post', :locals => {:post => post} %>
<% end %>
```

However, since that is a for-each loop I can't access two elements in one iteration to tell the loop to render two posts side by side on each row. How can I change this for-loop to render two posts side by side on one row?

Comment: That's more of a css question. Are you using a framework e.g. bootstrap/foundation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really had to output into two separate wrapper elements you would start by splitting the collection.

```
<% odd, even = arr.partition.with_index{ |_, i| i.even? } %>
<div class="column odd">
  <% odd.each do |post| %>
    <%= render :partial => 'post', :locals => {:post => post} %>
  <% end %>
</div>
<div class="column even">
  <% even.each do |post| %>
    <%= render :partial => 'post', :locals => {:post => post} %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Thats how it would have been done circa 2008 when you based your web design off a 720 or 960px width.

Nowadays this problem is better solved with [CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Columns/Using_multi-column_layouts).

Comment: I'm using bootstrap so that will give me responsive columns. This is what I needed, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Bootstrap, you can use something like this also

```
<% @posts.in_groups_of(2).each do |posts| %>
   <% # posts is an Array of 2 items %>
   <div class="col-md-4"><%= render :partial => 'post', :locals => {:post => posts[0]} %></div>
   <div class="col-md-4"><%= render :partial => 'post', :locals => {:post => posts[0]} %></div>
<% end %>
```